# how to set timeout on bufio.ReadBytes()

Tags: go

I am writing a code, which reads data from network with timeouts. Initially I wrote this (much simplified skipped error checks too)

```
func read_msg(conn net.Conn, ch chan []byte) {
    b := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    msg,_ := b.ReadBytes(byte('\n'))
    ch <- msg
    close(ch)
}

func main() {
    ln,_ := net.Listen("tcp", ":12345")
    conn,_ := ln.Accept()
    for {
        ch := make(chan []byte)
        go read_msg(conn,ch)
        select {
        case msg := <-ch:
            fmt.Println("message received: ", msg)
        case <-time.After(time.Duration(1)*time.Second):
            fmt.Println("timeout")
        }
    }
}
```

When the timeout happens, the goroutine stays active, waiting on the bufio.ReadBytes(). Is there anyway to set a timeout on the bufio itself?

Comment: The bufio.Reader does not implement timeouts. [Set a deadline in the connection](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn.SetReadDeadline) instead. Do not create a new bufio.Reader for every ReadBytes call. There is no reason to use a goroutine in the code above. If anything, create a goroutine per connection (maybe a second that handles writes), but not one per read.

Comment: You start goroutine in for, case matched after and continue  to next iterate with old goroutine and again and again and again

Answer (score 3):

No, `bufio` does not have this feature (you can read the docs [here](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader.ReadBytes)).

The more appropriate solution is to use the `SetReadDeadline` method of the [`net.Conn`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn) value.

```golang
    // A deadline is an absolute time after which I/O operations
    // fail instead of blocking. The deadline applies to all future
    // and pending I/O, not just the immediately following call to
    // Read or Write.
 ...
    // SetReadDeadline sets the deadline for future Read calls
    // and any currently-blocked Read call.
    // A zero value for t means Read will not time out.
```

For example:

```golang
conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second))
```